# Can I stop forEach until I get data from server with promise-then?

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, angular-promise

I'm trying to get img url from server using `promise-then`, and to update other object with that img url in server.

However, I can't update data because function which is for updating data triggers before downloading url, so it returns `null`.

So, I think if I could stop the running forEach until I get imgUrl then everything would work well.

**Here's my code**

---

**store.service.ts**

```js
addStoreImgList(imgArr, storeName) {
  const menuUrls = this.getStoreMenuImgUrl(imgArr.imgList, storeName);
  const normalUrls = this.getStoreNormalImgUrl(imgArr.normalImgList, storeName);

  return {menuUrls, normalUrls};
}

getStoreMenuImgUrl(menuImg, storeName) {
  const menuUrls = [];
  menuImg.forEach(item => {
    const imgRef = this.storageRef.child(`store/menuImg/${storeName}/${item.name}`);
    imgRef.put(item).then((snapshot) => menuUrls.push(snapshot.downloadURL));
  }); // Can I stop menuImg.forEach until I get a data from server here?

  return menuUrls;
}

getStoreNormalImgUrl(normalImg, storeName) {
  const normalUrls = [];
  normalImg.forEach(item => {
    const imgRef = this.storageRef.child(`store/normalImg/${storeName}/${item.name}`);
    imgRef.put(item).then((snapshot) => normalUrls.push(snapshot.downloadURL));
  });

  return normalUrls;
}
```

---

**edit-store.component.ts**

```js
const urls = this.storeService.addStoreImgList(imgArr, this.storeName);
```

---

If you could give way better advice, I would appreciate you.
I actually tried to use `observable` in `rxjs`, but I couldn't.

Thank you!

Comment: What's `normalImg`? That's an array of Observable?

Comment: No, it's a file image array

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a simple and easy way of doing this with "vanilla" promises. You can do it, but it requires you building a list of promises and chaining them together. That kind of code can get real ugly and complicated real fast.

The simplest way of doing this is to leverage the `async` `await` syntax.

What you're looking for should look something like like this:

```js
async getStoreMenuImgUrl(menuImg, storeName) {
  const menuUrls = [];
  for (const item of menuImg) {
    const imgRef = this.storageRef.child(`store/menuImg/${storeName}/${item.name}`);
    const snapshot = await imgRef.put(item);
    menuUrls.push(snapshot.downloadURL);
  }

  return menuUrls;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply!
I tried it like your code, but it made errors like this.
`ERROR Error: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom ZoneAwarePromise object (found in field menuPhotoList)
`

Comment: The caller function `addStoreImgList()` needs corresponding changes. `menuUrls` and `menuUrls` are now promises, which must be handled as such, and `addStoreImgList()` must also return a promise, which must be handled as such by its caller ...